# Could I have some help converting inner joins in sql into linq?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I want to use chained linq. I am having some trouble with the syntax.

```
select * from APPLES
inner join BANANAS on APPLES.id = BANANAS.someid
```

I have:

```
var result = workspace.GetDataSource<APPLE>().Join(.......)
```

but I am unsure about what goes into the Join bit. Could someone help me out?

Comment: You've probably read this but I don't know if it would help... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx

Comment: My lamda syntax for my edited answer was based upon this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767709/c-joins-where-with-linq-and-lambda

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
var result = from a in workspace.GetDataSource<APPLE>()
             from b in workspace.GetDataSource<BANANAS>()
             where a.id == b.someid
             select a;
```

or if you want to use join notation:

```
var result = from a in workspace.GetDataSource<APPLE>()
             join b in workspace.GetDataSource<BANANAS>()
             on a.id equals b.someid
             select a;
```

Note, you can change the select a to a projection of the elements you need from both tables.

Not as familiar with this format, but it would be something like this:

```
var result = workspace.GetDataSource<APPLE>().Join(workspace.GetDataSource<BANANAS>(),a=>a.id, b=>b.someid,(a,b) => a);
```

Comment: I'd like to use the join notation, but using .join