# MVC3 Linq query adding to list

Tags: c#, list, generics

I'm trying to build a list of software names from `db.tblSoftwares` by using a query.

I've tried to use `.Add` method and it will not work.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
   // this gets the hostname based on id//
   tblComputer tblcomputer = db.tblComputers.Find(id);
   var workstation  = tblcomputer.HostName;

   // next want to get the list of software names assigned to host name//

   // get the list of licenses for hostname based on id/
   var Licenses = (from n in db.tblLicenses
                   where n.tblComputerComputerId == id
                   select n.tblSoftwareSoftwareId).ToList();

   List<string> appslist = new List<string>();

   foreach (var l in Licenses)
   {
       var query1 = (from s in db.tblSoftwares
                     where s.SoftwareId == l
                     select new { s.Name }).ToList();

       // appslist = query1;           
   }                         

   var swList = new List<string> { "Adobe", "MS Office", "MS Visio" };

   var ViewModel = new ComputerSoftwareViewModel
   {
       HostName = workstation,
       Applications = swList                
   };

   return View(ViewModel);
}
```

Comment: I posted before I asked the question: I'm sure there is a better way at doing this but this was the best I could understand to do. I'm trying to build a list of software names from db.tblSoftwares by using a query. I've tried to use .add method and it will not work. Any suggestions would be appreciated. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Join the two tables and select the new list directly.

try this:
[C# Joins/Where with Linq and Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767709/c-sharp-joins-where-with-linq-and-lambda)