# LINQ - can't create a request

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Hello I have the following structure:

```
Table Countries:
- CountryID
- CountryName

Table Records:
- RecordID
- RecordName
- CountryID
```

This LINQ returns list of all countries "as is":

```
 (from i in db.Countries 
 select new SelectListItem() 
 { 
     Text = i.CountryName, 
     Value = i.CountryID.ToString() 
 }).ToList();
```

I want to sort this list of countries such way: The most popular countries in "Records" table to the top list. How to do it?

Comment: use join http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767709/c-sharp-joins-where-with-linq-and-lambda

Comment: You need a column that quantifies popularity so you can sort by that column.

Comment: flipdoubt, I don't want to have one more column, I want to sort it depends on Records table

Comment: If you are saying the number of times CountyId appears in the Records table quantifies a country's popularity, you should state that more clearly. The structure provides no reason to make that assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
(from i in db.Countries 
 join r in db.Records on i.CountryID equals r.CountryID into rds
 orderby rds.Count() descending
 select new SelectListItem() 
 { 
     Text = i.CountryName, 
     Value = i.CountryID.ToString() 
 }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  var  recordsItem=db.Records.GroupBy(x=> x.CountryID).Select( gr => new{ CID=gr.Key, Count=gr.Count()}).ToList();

  var result= (from c in db.Countries
              join  r in  recordsItem on c.CountryID equals r.CID
              order by r.Count descending
              select  new  SelectListItem() 
               {
                  Text = c.CountryName, 
                  Value =   c.CountryID.ToString()
               }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, but: Additional information: Unable to create a constant value of type 'Anonymous type'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Comment: On which query you got this error? Please use latest code, I have modified it just now

Comment: The same. On second query