# how to get data from two tables using linq in mvc c#

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

i'm new to linq and mvc so far this is to get name base on name search

```
return repository.GetAll().Where(
    m => m.Name.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower()));
```

however, i want to be able to get information from another table that associated with name like address, city, etc.. base on the name search. so at the end if i type in Pete, it will returns.

```
pete a, 111 test ave, holland, usa;
pete c, 222 test rd, holland, usa;
```

can someone help please. thanks

Comment: Have a look to the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767709/c-sharp-joins-where-with-linq-and-lambda

Comment: What does your database schema look like?

Comment: really just 3 tables one has id, name, one has id address, and one has nameid, addressid. so when you search for a name,  i want to be able to pull all addresses that that person has been to or if you search for address i want to pull all people that were at the search address.

Comment: any help is really aprreciated

Comment: Whether or not you need `ToLower` depends on the database collation, You may not need it at all. But what exactly is your problem in combining the data into one result?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like..

```
var joinedQuery = from n in names
                  join a in address on n.name equals a.name
                  select new { aName = n.name, anAddress = a.address };
```

names is your names repository and address is the addressed repository

Comment: how do i ignore the case sensitive in name

Comment: use .ToLower() on both strings