# LINQ match objects in set A in set B

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say we have 2 sets

> A = [ PersonA,PersonB];
>
> B = [ ManagerZ,ManagerT,ManagerY];
>
> Result : ManagerT,ManagerY

There exists One to One mapping between the objects in A and the objects in B.
I'm interested in those objects in B for which exists such an entry in A.

For completeness let's say we are matching on property named `Name`

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767709/c-sharp-joins-where-with-linq-and-lambda

Comment: To get it clear: you want all the objects `b` from set `B` for which there exists an object `a` in set `A` such that `a.Name == b.Name`?

Comment: @chris `SetA.Where(el => SetA.Any(a => a.Name == el.Name)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following

```
SetB.Where(b => SetA.Any(a => a.Name == b.Name))
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to perform a join on both lists:

```
var query =
    from person in persons
    join manager in managers on person.Name equals manager.Name
    select new { Person = person, Manager = manager };
```

This will select all data from your `Person`-dataset together with the corresponding data from `Manager`-dataset.

Alternativly you can flatten the results into a datatype providing the whole data for every match:

```
    select new { Name = person.Name, Age = person.Age, Departement = Manager.Departement }
```

Or if you´re only interested on the items from `B` which match use simply `select manager`.

Comment: Argumentation why I didn't accept your answer : I was looking for something simpler than the answer I accepted. This adds a lot of boilerplate code. I assume the complexity of either solutions is O(N^2) so I would always take the simpler one. If I'm wrong and there is some optimization from your approach I would gladly take your answer. Thanks

Comment: This could result in duplicate manager objects if there are multiple name matches with the person list.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code:

```
List<BType> result = B.Where(x >= A.Exists(y => y.Name == x.Name)).ToList();
```

In this way you mantain only managers that exists in people list.

Comment: Should be noted that this only works if `A` is a `List<Person>` as `Exists` is an instance method of `List<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use Intersect.
Example:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class PersonEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Person>
{
    public bool Equals(Person x, Person y)
    {
        return x.Name.Equals(x.Name);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Person obj)
    {
        return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And now you can use:

```
var persons = new List<Person>() { new Person { Name = "John" } };
var managers = new List<Person>() { new Person { Name = "John" } };
var results = persons.Intersect(managers, new PersonEqualityComparer());
```

If you want compare two different class just edit Comparer.