# Entity Framework linq join/association

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to do a join/ association in entity framework using linq.

I have the following two tables:

### Institution

id
name
country_code(same as iso3)
etc...

### Country

id
name
iso3

I have tried the following but i'm getting stuck at where to associate the objects with each other:

```
List<Institution> ins = _context.Institution
                                .Include(o => o.country)
```

thanks

Comment: It seems fine to me but try to log the generated SQL by using this _context.Database.Log = s => Debug.WriteLine(s). Also check the relation between your classes

Answer (score 2):

if iso3 and country_code is not bound with a foreign constraint you should use .Join for lambda expression. Check the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2767742/2630427)

Answer (score 1):

```
var ins = 
    _context.Institution
    .Join(_context.Country, 
          inst => inst.country_code,        
          ctry => ctry.iso3,   
         (inst, ctry) => new { Institution = inst, Country = ctry }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, I've added an extra column to the institution table called country_id, i'm sure there's probably a way I could have mapped the country_code of country to the institution entity, but I took the quick and easy way out.

Thanks again