# Cannot figure out this complex query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have three tables and I am having trouble getting to the bottom of this one.

So I am given the ID of a vehicle, and I need to write a query to output a list of its seat rows.

```
Vehicle
{
id,
vehicleTypeId,
color
}
VehicleType
{
id,
type,
}
VehicleSeats
{
id,
description
}
```

This is as far as my query has gotten and I am just as a complete loss on getting this one out right. I need it to output a list of seats, not a list of types, I just do not know how to take it deeper.

```
var vehicleSeatsList = (from c in db.Vehicle
                                where c.VehicleTypeID == id
                                select c).ToList();
```

Here was my final solution. I have yet to plug it in to know if it is right. I was being a dummy. Dont know why I wasn't thinking of just doing a join...

```
var VehicleTypeSeats = (from c in db.VehicleTypeSeats
                                join a in db.Vehicles on c.AircraftTypeID equals a.VehicleTypeID
                                where c.VehicleTypeID == id
                                select c).ToList();
```

Comment: that is NOT a complex query. Is it the Vehicle ID you have (c.ID?)

Comment: Yes, the VehicleID is "id". Also, I know that it isn't that complex, I just have never worked with Linq before.

Comment: When you have EF related question, post your entity **classes**, not just table and column names. It would be much easier for you and for the people trying to help you.

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767709/c-sharp-joins-where-with-linq-and-lambda - you really just need to do a join.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is in SQL, there is no relationship between your `VehicleSeats` and `Vehicle` tables. You would need to add `VehicleSeats.vehicleID` or something like that. If you did, the below would work:

`SELECT VehicleSeats.description 
FROM VehicleSeats, Vehicle 
WHERE VehicleSeats.vehicleID = Vehicle.id
AND Vehicle.id = {your given vehicle ID};`

Comment: Im doing it in linq and that is the part that I am confused about.

Comment: Sorry dude no experience with that

Answer (score 0):

Simply inner join Vehicle and Vehicle seats on their common column then add the where statement.

```
var VehicleTypeSeats = (from c in db.VehicleTypeSeats
   join a in db.Vehicles on c.AircraftTypeID equals a.VehicleTypeID
   where c.VehicleTypeID == id
   select c).ToList();
```