# How to write IQueryable Join using lambda?

Tags: c#, iqueryable

I have next table:

```
MyTable
(
ParentId Integer,
Type Integer,
ProdId String,
Date DateTime,
Status Integer
);
```

I want to query as next:

```
var res = from tout in myTable.Where(t1 => t1.Type == 1)
                join tin in myTable.Where(t2 => t2.Type != 1)
        on tout.ParentId equals tin.ParentId
                where tout.ProdId == tin.ProdId && tout.Status > tin.Status
                orderby tout.Date
                select new MyTableStructure
                {
            ...
        };
```

How to write same as `IQueryable` using lambda?

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but from researching (b/c I didn't know how to do it either), it seems that both syntax look identical. However, it's the type that you're assigning to that makes the difference. (ie - `IQueryable<MyTableStructure> res = .....` vs `IEnumerable<MyTableStructure> res = .....`.  http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/linq/ienumerable-vs-iqueryable

Comment: OK. Added that I also want to use lambda

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I recommend whenever using `Joins` in LINQ queries to always use the standard method instead of lambda. Reason being is that the `Join` syntax gets a little confusing (at least for me), and is easier read using the standard way.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767709/c-sharp-joins-where-with-linq-and-lambda

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this

```
var query1 = myTable.Where(t1 => t1.Type == 1);
var query2 = myTable.Where(t2 => t2.Type != 1);
var join = query1.Join(query2, x => x.ParentId, y => y.ParentId, (query1, query2) => new { query1 , query2 }).Where(o => o.query1.ProdId == o.qyuery2.prodId).......
```

your order by next and Something

Comment: Thanks a lot! The only note (it takes me some time to realize what's exactly wrong) - new { query2 , query1 }  - wise-versa order should be there, to match with original join