# Multiply two columns in two tables with linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I need this this **sql query in c#** :

```
Select cv.manv, cv.luong1h*ct.sogiolam
From congviec cv 
inner join chitiet ct on cv.manv=ct.manv
```

How can I do it with LINQ to sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from cv in congviec
join ct in chitiet on cv.manv equals ct.manv
select new { cv.manv, cv.luong1h*ct.sogiolam}
```

sorry my bad, see this edit for working solution

```
var list = (from cv in congviec
    join ct in chitiet on cv.manv equals ct.manv
    select new { cv.manv, Multiply = cv.luong1h*ct.sogiolam}).toList();
```

Comment: thank for your answer but it give a error
 Error for cv.luong1h*ct.sogiolam: 
Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Comment: glad to help :) .toList() is required if you are returning more than 1 items. else you can have firstordefault() or remove as you did. :)

Comment: yead. Tks for help !! I don't know where you are but in my country it is 22h14' good night!!

Answer (score 0):

It would look almost the same in Linq

```
var ExampleVariable = (from cv in congviec 
                         inner join ct chitiet
                         on cv.manv equals ct.manv
                         select new { 
                                cv.manv,
                                //cv.luong1h*ct.sogiolam
                                Product =  cv.luong1h*ct.sogiolam
                                }).ToList();
```

And using lambda expression, refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2767742/6170109).

Hope this helps.