# How to join two tables with one table having distinct value in LINQ sql?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I have two tables `emp_details` where i have `emp_id`, `emp_name` and `emp_addresss` as columns and another table `emp_hierarcy` where i have `emp_id`, `emp_mgid` with multiple rows with same `emp_id`.

I want to write a linq query i.e, to join two table upon `emp_id`  with distinct emp_id in `emp_hierarcy`. I know how to join tables in sqlserver and i have return this query in sqlserver

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT
    eh.emp_id
FROM
    emp_details ed
    LEFT OUTER JOIN emp_hierarcy eh ON ed.emp_id = eh.emp_id
```

i'm able to print only `emp_id` how to get all the details in LINQ query ?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767709/c-sharp-joins-where-with-linq-and-lambda. To get the distinct values, the `enumerable` should have a `Distinct` method.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? You generally don't need to perform JOINs in Linq-to-Entities if you use Navigation Properties.

Comment: Look at GROUP BY and how to do it in Linq.

Comment: @Dai how is it possible actually can you please explain me with an example im new to MVC

Answer (score 1):

Select all fields that you are interested in:

```
var items = (from a in emp_details
           join b in emp_hierarcy on a.emp_id equals b.emp_id
           select new 
           {
               emp_id = a.emp_id,
               emp_name = a.emp_name,
               emp_address = a.emp_address,
               emp_mgid = b.emp_mgid
           }).Distinct();

foreach(var item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.emp_address);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(from a in emp_details
               join b in emp_hierarcy on a.emp_id equals b.emp_id
               select new 
               {
               emp_id = a.emp_id
               }).Distinct();
```

Alternatively you can try,

```
(from a in emp_details
               join b in emp_hierarcy on a.emp_id equals b.emp_id
               select new 
               {
               emp_id = a.emp_id
               }).DistinctBy(c => c.emp_id)
```

Comment: this one i have tried but how do i get all details i.e, emp_name ,emp_ address etc because it only prints emp_id right 
the thing is i need to print all the details.

Comment: Add all fields you want inside select

Comment: Can you please share your data so that I write query on top of that