# how can i write sql query with join and where clause in linq or lambda

Tags: c#, linq

I wrote below query in `MsSQL` now I want to write this query using C# `linq`

```
SELECT JD.*
FROM Job_Details JD
INNER JOIN MstCustomer Cust ON JD.Cust_ID = Cust.Cust_ID
WHERE Cust.SAP = 'Yes'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767709/join-where-with-linq-and-lambda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fairly simple `join` would do.

```
from jd in Job_Details 
join cust in MstCustomer
on jd.Cust_ID equals cust.Cust_ID
where cust.SAP == 'Yes'
select jd
```

Answer (score 1):

You asked for it using a lambda expression

You only want the Customers with Cust.SAP equal to "Yes", but you don't want the SAP in the end result. Hence it is more efficient to join only with the customers you actually want in your final result. Therefore do the `Where` before the `Join`:

```
IQueryable<JobDetail> jobDetails = ...
IQueryable<Customer> mstCustomers = ...

// Step 1: filter only the Yes customers:
var yesCustomers = mstCustomers.Where(customer => customer.SAP == "Yes");

// Step 2: Perform the join and select the properties you want:
var result = jobDetails.Join(yesCustomers, // Join jobDetails and yesCustomers
   jobDetail => jobDetail.Cust_Id,         // from every jobDetail take the Cust_Id
   customer = customer.Cust_Id,            // from every customer take the Cust_Id
   (jobDetail, customer) => new            // when they match use the matching items
   {                                       // to create a new object
       // select only the properties
       // from jobDetail and customer
       // you really plan to use
   })
```

TODO: if desired, make it one big LINQ statement. Note that this doesn't influence the performance very much, as these statements do not perform the query. They only change the  `Expression` of the query. Only items that do not return `IQueryable` perform the query: ToList / FirstOrDefault / Any / Max / ...