# Converting a Linq statement in VB to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I have the following line in VB

```
Dim Totalstock = (From stock In StockInfo.Record, locs In Location.BranchList Where locs.Key.Item1 = "Deliver" And locs.Key.Item2 = stock.WHLO Select stock).ToArray
```

which i need to translate to C#. I am used to using the lambda statements in Linq, but with this query I have no idea how to convert it.

Perhaps anyone who could help me out?

Comment: You can use Teleriks converter: http://converter.telerik.com

Comment: Sadly, Telerik spazzed out when I threw this in it.

Comment: [Join/Where with LINQ and Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2767742/1115360) might interest you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var Totalstock = (
    from stock in StockInfo.Record
    from locs in Location.BranchList
    where locs.Key.Item1 == "Deliver" && locs.Key.Item2 == stock.WHLO
    select stock).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful, I see that i have a lot to learn when it comes to this.

Comment: @DennisLukas ps i just used the free version of "Instant C#", which basically you can give less than 200 lines of VB and it will convert to c# for you ;-)

Comment: Hahaha I tried telerik and others, but there are so many bad ones. Im gonna try this one, thanks!

Comment: @DennisLukas yeah i know been through the same process which you are, this one is the only one which is any good.

Comment: You can use IL Spy to decompile your VB dll into C#