# Converting SQL query to LINQ or LINQ fluent Syntax

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, ef-code-first

I have SQL query like this

```
SELECT T.*
FROM 
(
SELECT ServiceRecords.DistrictId, Districts.Name as DistrictName, COUNT(Distinct(NsepServiceRecords.ClientRegNo)) AS ClientsServedCount 
FROM ServiceRecords
INNER JOIN Districts ON ServiceRecords.DistrictId = Districts.ID
INNER JOIN NsepServiceRecords ON NsepServiceRecords.ServiceRecordId = ServiceRecords.Id
WHERE ServiceRecords.CreatedAtUtc >= @StartDate
AND ServiceRecords.CreatedAtUtc <= @EndDate
AND ServiceRecords.DistrictId = @DistrictId
GROUP BY ServiceRecords.DistrictId, Districts.Name
) AS T
ORDER BY T.DistrictName ASC, T.DistrictId
```

Query results:

```
DistrictId                              DistrictName    ClientsServedCount
8d059005-1e6b-44ad-bc2c-0b3264fb4567    Bahawalpur      117
27ab6e24-50a6-4722-8115-dc31cd3127fa    Gujrat          492
14b648f3-4912-450e-81f9-bf630a3dfc72    Jhelum          214
8c602b99-3308-45b5-808b-3375d61fdca0    Lodhran         23
059ffbea-7787-43e8-bd97-cab7cb77f6f6    Muzafarghar     22
580ee42b-3516-4546-841c-0bd8cef04df9    Peshawar        211
```

I'm struggling converting this to LINQ to entities query. I want to get same results (except District Id column) using LINQ.

I have tried like this, but not working as expected. Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
_dbContext.ServiceRecords
.Include(x => x.District)
.Include(x=>x.NsepServiceRecords)
.GroupBy(x => x.DistrictId)
.Select(x => new DistrictClientsLookUpModel
{
    DistrictName = x.Select(record => record.District.Name).FirstOrDefault(),
    ClientsServedCount = x.Sum(t=> t.NsepServiceRecords.Count)
});
```

Model classes are like this

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class NsepServiceRecord : BaseEntity
{
    public DateTime CreatedAtUtc { get; set; }

    public Guid ServiceRecordId { get; set; }

    public string ClientRegNo { get; set; }
    // other prop .......

    public virtual ServiceRecord ServiceRecord { get; set; }
}

public class ServiceRecord : BaseEntity
{
    public DateTime CreatedAtUtc { get; set; }
    public string DistrictId { get; set; }

    public virtual District District { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<NsepServiceRecord> NsepServiceRecords { get; set; }

}

public class DistrictClientsLookUpModel
{
    public string DistrictName { get; set; }
    public int ClientsServedCount { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version 2.2.4`

**EDIT**
I have also tried like this

```
var startUniversalTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(request.StartDate, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var endUniversalTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(request.EndDate, DateTimeKind.Utc);
return _dbContext.NsepServiceRecords
.Join(_dbContext.ServiceRecords, s => s.ServiceRecordId,
    r => r.Id, (s, r) => r)
.Include(i => i.District)
.Where(x => x.DistrictId == request.DistrictId
            && x.CreatedAtUtc.Date >= startUniversalTime
            && x.CreatedAtUtc.Date <= endUniversalTime)
.OrderBy(x => x.DistrictId)
.GroupBy(result => result.DistrictId)

.Select(r => new DistrictClientsLookUpModel
{
    DistrictName = r.Select(x=>x.District.Name).FirstOrDefault(),
    ClientsServedCount = r.Sum(x=>x.NsepServiceRecords.Count())
});
```

Another try,

```
from s in _dbContext.ServiceRecords
join record in _dbContext.NsepServiceRecords on s.Id equals record.ServiceRecordId
join district in _dbContext.Districts on s.DistrictId equals district.Id
group s by new
{
    s.DistrictId,
    s.District.Name
}
into grp
select new DistrictClientsLookUpModel
{
    DistrictName = grp.Key.Name,
    ClientsServedCount = grp.Sum(x => x.NsepServiceRecords.Count)
};
```

It takes too long, I waited for two minutes before I killed the request.

**UPDATE**

EF core have [issues](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12255) translating `GroupBy` queries to server side

Comment: Side note: why do you join entities that don't contribute to the end result? Another note: *if* you're gonna need these entities, don't join but use these nice navigation properties you have. Then: the long execution time probably means that EF is auto-switching to client-side evaluation which means that it pulls far too many data from the database. Check the executed SQL.

Comment: @GetArnold EF is evaluating my first example query locally. Getting warnings like `The LINQ expression 'Sum()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.`

Comment: Yep, there you go. EF core still isn't capable of translating somewhat complex LINQ queries into fully server-side evaluated SQL. Nothing you can do about it other than working around the issue by ugly solutions like running raw SQL or creating views/stored procedures for anything that EF can't handle properly.

Comment: @GetArnold I used `Query Types` for the solution that uses Raw sql. But I wasn't satisfied. I hope this resolves in EF core 3.0.

Comment: Don't hold your breath...

Comment: Do I have choice?

Comment: One point that you may want to be careful regarding you query is, do the Where Filtering before joining data, just changing the sequence may make your query faster, since you are doing it on `ServiceRecords` data, which is then joined with other tables / collections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `District` has a collection navigation property to `ServiceRecord` as it should, e.g. something like

```
public virtual ICollection<ServiceRecord> ServiceRecords { get; set; }
```

you can avoid the `GroupBy` by simply starting the query from `District` and use simple projection `Select` following the navigations:

```
var query = _dbContext.Districts
    .Select(d => new DistrictClientsLookUpModel
    {
        DistrictName = d.Name,
        ClientsServedCount = d.ServiceRecords
            .Where(s => s.CreatedAtUtc >= startUniversalTime && s.CreatedAtUtc <= endUniversalTime)
            .SelectMany(s => s.NsepServiceRecords)
            .Select(r => r.ClientRegNo).Distinct().Count()
    });
```

Comment: I do have navigation property to `ServiceRecord` in `District`. I totally forgot about this navigation property :D.

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be doing a join properly.

Have a look at this: 
[Join/Where with LINQ and Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767709/join-where-with-linq-and-lambda)

Here is a start on the linq query, I'm not sure if this will give you quite what you want, but its a good start.

Basically within the .Join method you need to first supply the entity that will be joined. Then you need to decide on what they will be joined on, in this case district=> district.Id, serviceRecord=> serviceRecord.Id.

```
_dbContext.ServiceRecords
.Join( _dbContext.District,district=> district.Id, serviceRecord=> serviceRecord.Id)
.Join(_dbContext.NsepServiceRecords, Nsep=> Nsep.ServiceRecord.Id,district=>district.Id)
.GroupBy(x => x.DistrictId)
.Select(x => new DistrictClientsLookUpModel
{
  DistrictName = x.Select(record => record.District.Name).FirstOrDefault(),
  ClientsServedCount = x.Sum(t=> t.NsepServiceRecords.Count)
});
```

Comment: I'm getting exception at `.Join(x => x.District,district=> district.Id, serviceRecord=> serviceRecord.Id)`. `No overload for method 'Join' takes 3 arguments`. Do I need to add reference to any assembly?

Comment: still getting same exception on `Join`.