# Joining results from two queries in C# using LINQ or other module

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, asp.net-web-api

I have two queries taking data from a single table with lambda and I would like to use something like a SQL 'join on' method in order to join the tables on a single id. The queries are:

```
    var tbl_emails_received =
        db.EmailAddresses
        .GroupBy(x => new { x.RecepientID })
        .Select(x => new
        {
            x.Key.RecepientID,
            EmailsRecieved = x.Count()

        });
```

and

```
        var tbl_emails_sent =
        db.EmailAddresses
        .GroupBy(x => new { x.SenderID })
        .Select(x => new
        {
            x.Key.SenderID,
            EmailsSent = x.Count()
        });
```

I am trying to replicate what this MsSQL Query is doing. I tried looking at Microsoft's documentation for `join` ([linked here](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause)) but it requires new classes to hold the objects.

```
WITH 
tbl_emails_received AS
    (
        SELECT RecepientID, count(FileID) AS EmailsRecieved 
        FROM tbl_ex_EmailAddresses
        GROUP BY RecepientID
    ),
tbl_emails_sent AS
    (
        SELECT SenderId, count(FileID) AS EmailsSent
        FROM tbl_ex_EmailAddresses
        GROUP BY SenderID
    )

SELECT s.SenderID as Id, r.EmailsRecieved, s.EmailsSent, 
    r.EmailsRecieved + s.EmailsSent as TotalEmails,
    slist.EmailAddress, slist.EmailName, slist.DomainName
FROM tbl_emails_received r
    JOIN tbl_emails_sent s
        ON r.RecepientID = s.SenderID
```

But it could be that LINQ or C# cannot create objects on the fly like with SQL does with the data. My question is, is there a way I can replicate what the SQL query is doing in LINQ or simple C#? Are there any best practices for this kind of queries? Is there another package I could use that could potentially make this simpler?

Comment: This probably help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767709/join-where-with-linq-and-lambda

Comment: As the two LINQ queries are not executed at this stage and are using anonymous types then join them into a type that returns your required results.

Comment: I wonder if your data model is correct. I don't understand what an `EmailAddress` needs a sender and a recipient id for. I feel that a better data model would make it easier to get the information you need. If you're in for improvement in this area consider posting a new question, *maybe* on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @GertArnold I agree. The dataModel is a bit misleading but it has been used for a while so it's hard to fix it without making large scale changes in the Database and the .NET Project. The EmailAddressID actually represents one email sent from a Sender to a Receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this (using your two initial queries)

```
var query = (from er in tbl_emails_received 
            join es in tbl_emails_sent on er.RecepientID equals es.SenderID
            select new emailsReceieved = er, emailsSent = es
            ).ToList();
EMailClass finalClass = query.select(
            x => new EMailClass
            {
            Id = x.emailsSent.SenderID,
            EmailsReceived = x.emailsReceieved.EmailsRecieved
            ...
            }).ToList();
```

This has not been tested or fully checked. The only trip to the database is the creation of `query`. There is only one class which is the one that is equivalent to the output from your SQL `SELECT` statement. (And it has to go somewhere). Or, you could also make that an anonymous class.

Answer (score 1):

run select query on db.EmailAddresses .ToList() to get all records from table, now run group by for recipientId , SenderId on top of this query. This way database hit is once only