# LINQ-to-Entities query on Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm having a hard time creating a LINQ-to-Entities query that would fulfill my requirement.

I have two tables: `Booking` and `ProcessStatusLog`.

**Booking** table:

- PNNumber (PK)
- AccountName

**ProcessStatusLog** table:

- ID (PK)
- PNNumber (FK)
- InsuranceCode
- Status
- UpdatedOn

Here is the sample data for these tables:

**Booking** table

```
| PNNumber | Account Name   |
+----------+----------------+
| 11111    | Boston Celtics |
| 22222    | Miami Heat     |
| 33333    | LA Lakers      |
```

**ProcessStatusLog** table:

```
| ID   | PNNumber  | InsuranceCode | Status       | UpdatedOn   |
+------+-----------+---------------+--------------+-------------+
| 1    | 11111     | null          | NEW          | 02/22/2020  |
| 2    | 11111     | FIRE          | FOR REVIEW   | 02/23/2020  |
| 3    | 22222     | null          | NEW          | 02/24/2020  |
| 4    | 22222     | MORTGAGE      | FOR REVIEW   | 02/25/2020  |
| 5    | 22222     | MORTGAGE      | CORRECTION   | 02/26/2020  |
| 6    | 22222     | FIRE          | FOR REVIEW   | 02/27/2020  |
| 7    | 33333     | null          | NEW          | 02/28/2020  |
| 8    | 22222     | FIRE          | APPROVED     | 02/29/2020  |
```

Now, I want to get a list of bookings per latest status.

For example: if I want to filter the bookings where the latest status is "CORRECTION", I will get the booking with PNNumber 22222.

If searching for "FOR REVIEW", I will just get the booking with PNNumber 11111.

If searching for "NEW", I will just get the booking with PNNumber 33333.

How can I write the EF query for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post some queries that you have tried and Does your `ProcessStatusLog` have a Navigation key to `Booking`?

Comment: Wouldn't `FOR REVIEW` = `22222` ? if not, you will need to explain why

Comment: @MichaelRandall 22222 will not be included in the desired result for FOR REVIEW because I am querying for the latest status. The FOR REVIEW in 22222 status has already been "overwritten" by the CORRECTION and APPROVED status.

Comment: @vikscool Yes the `ProcessStatusLog` has a Navigation key to `Booking`. One booking can have many process status logs.

Answer (score 1):

```
context.ProcessStatusLog.where(x=>x.Status == "FOR REVIEW")
                        .OrderByDescending(x => x.UpdatedOn)
                        .Take(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Join()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767709/join-where-with-linq-and-lambda) to achieve it.

```
var result = context.ProcessStatusLog.Join(context.Booking, s => s.PNNumber, b => b.PNNumber, (s, b) => new { booking = b, StatusLog = s).Where(BookingAndStatusLog => BookingAndStatusLog.StatusLog.Status == your_parameter)
                        .OrderByDescending(BookingAndStatusLog  => BookingAndStatusLog.StatusLog.UpdatedOn)
                        .Take(1);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @kuriboh

Answer (score 0):

Try below Query.

```
context.ProcessStatusLog.where(x=>x.Status == "FOR REVIEW")
.OrderByDescending(x => x.UpdatedOn)
.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

So far my understanding of your question, you can try-

```
var result= context.ProcessStatusLog.OrderByDescending(x => x.UpdatedOn)
                        .FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Status == "CORRECTION");
```

**OR**

```
var result= context.ProcessStatusLog.where(x=>x.Status == "CORRECTION")
                        .OrderByDescending(x => x.UpdatedOn)
                        .FirstOrDefault();
```

it's return a single object of your `ProcessStatusLog` class.

Answer (score -1):

```
using (var ctx = new SchoolDBEntities())
{
var student = ctx.Students
                .SqlQuery("Select top1 from ProcessStatusLog where Status like '%"+@APPROVED+"%' order by UpdatedOn", new SqlParameter("@APPROVE", yourinputparameter))
                .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: That's not what the question asked for and is flat-out awful code.