# Find all objects in one list that have a property that matches a property in another list of objects

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

**Problem**

I am attempting to query a table (based on `ModelA`) using another table (based on ModelB). These models are simplified for this example. I need to keep the result as an `IQueryable`, so changing to an `Enumerable` or `List` are not options. Still, I tried adding `.ToList()` but got the same error.

Pulling the `MyId`s out of one list into a list of strings (in order to use `Contains()`) isn't an option since there may be too many `MyIds` (> 40k) that causes an error indicating the operation as run out of resources, which I would guess refers to RAM.

**Error**

> InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression ... could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().

**ModelA**

```
public class ModelA
{
    public string MyId { get; set; }
    public string MyName { get; set; }
}
```

**ModelB**

```
public class ModelB
{
    public string MyId { get; set; }
    public string MyName { get; set; }
}
```

**Attempt**

```
var results = context.ModelA
            .Where(a => ModelB.All(b => b.MyId == a.MyId));
```

What way(s) can this be done successfully?

Comment: `var results = context.ModelA.Where(a => ModelB.Any(b => b.MyId == a.MyId));`

Comment: Yes, `Any` is the correct method for this. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could try checking to see if the second list contains 'Any()'  of matching ID

```
var results = context.ModelA
        .Where(a => ModelB.Where(b => b.MyId == a.MyId).Any());
```

or you might want to try Join

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause

```
var results = context.ModelA
    .Where(a => ModelB.
            Any(b => b!= null  && b.id != null 
                  && a!=null && a.id!==null && 
                  b.MyId == a.MyId));
```

I had Select instead of Where and I've checked for nulls

Comment: Both options work, but the `Join` option is slower than the `Where` so I went with the faster one. I had to create a view for `ModelB` so that it was accessible from the same context as `ModelA` (they are in different databases). Choosing your answer since you were first.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
var results = ctx
    .ModelAs
    .Where(ma => ctx.ModelBs.Any(mb => mb.MyId == ma.MyId));
```

I used your models, this is my `DbContext`:

```
public class MockContext : DbContext
{
    public MockContext(DbContextOptions<MockContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<ModelA> ModelAs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ModelB> ModelBs { get; set; }
}
```

The data I used to test this was:

ModelA:

```
MyId | MyName

1 Nettie Koch 
2 Karl Kuvalis 
3 Marcus Weissnat 
4 Shannon Hettinger 
5 Wilma Kuvalis 
6 Benny Brown 
7 Amanda Maggio 
8 Claude Kohler 
9 Dawn Ritchie 
10 Alan Ruecker
```

ModelB:

```
MyId | MyName

5 Francis Konopelski 
6 Mandy Yost 
7 Marsha Parisian 
8 Crystal Mayer 
9 Sergio Crona 
10 Kenny Rice 
11 Levi Gutkowski 
12 Brandon Haley 
13 Jan Kunze 
14 Rafael Blanda
```

Result:

```
MyId | MyName

5 Wilma Kuvalis 
6 Benny Brown 
7 Amanda Maggio 
8 Claude Kohler 
9 Dawn Ritchie 
10 Alan Ruecker
```

Comment: Great, thorough answer that works, thank you. I had to create a view for `ModelB` so that it was accessible from the same context as `ModelA` (they are in different databases).

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways you can achieve it, here are two ways for your reference:

```
var result = (from a in context.ModelA
                      join b in context.ModelB
                      on a.MyId equals b.MyId
                      select a);
```

Or you can try this method:

```
 var result = context.ModelA.Join(_context.ModelB,
                        x => x.MyId,
                        y => y.MyId,
                       (x, y) => x);
```

You can refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767709/join-where-with-linq-and-lambda) for more details.

Comment: Thank you, I tried the `Join` and it worked. It's a little slower than `Where` for some reason. I also had to create a view for `ModelB` so that it was accessible from the same context as `ModelA` (they are in different databases).

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking `Any()` like below

```
var results = context.ModelA.Where(a => ModelB.Any(b => b.MyId == a.MyId));
```

Comment: As I mentioned in comment section. You can use `Any()` to achieve it. Don't forget to accept my answer if it was helpful to you.