# How to Convert Inner Join SQL Query to Lambda Expression

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

How to convet this inner join sql query to lamda expression

```html
SELECT
   f.ID,Floor_Name,Campus_Name,c.ID,Building_Name,b.ID
FROM
    Floors f
INNER JOIN Campus c ON c.ID = f.CampusID
INNER JOIN Buildings b ON b.ID = f.BuildingID
```

Comment: SQL is a declarative language, while a lambda expression is an imperative construct. This won't be a loss-less conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your SQL query can be translated to the following EF Query

```
var result = from floor in floors
join c in campus on c.Id equals floor.CampusId
join b in Buildings on b.Id equals floor.BuildingId
select new {
floor.Id, floor.Floor_Name, c.Campus_Name, c.Id, b.Building_Name, b.Id
};
```

you can use a ToList() if you don't have any filters to be applied to the EF Query

In case you wanted to refer additional filters, pls check here: [Join/Where with LINQ and Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767709/join-where-with-linq-and-lambda)