# How do I apply a Where clause to an entity that's a couple layers deep in a LINQ expression?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm working on a LINQ expression that will pull in related tables to a Person table we've got. The query I've written does work, but it takes a long time to run and brings back more data than I need. Here's the LINQ expression I have now:

```cs
using (var ctx = new AppEntities())
{
    People = ctx.People.Where(p => p.Inactive == false)
        .Include(p => p.Agency)
        .Include(p => p.PersonnelCertifications.Select(pc => pc.CertificationType))
        .OrderBy(p => p.LastName)
        .ThenBy(p => p.FirstName)
        .ToList();
}
```

We're working with .NET 4.5.2 and EF 6.4. The Person table has a relatonship with the PersonnelCertification table. And that has a relationship with the CertificationType table. Ideally, what I need to add is a filter so that only CertificationType.CertType == "Operator". I tried adding a Where clause after the Include of PersonnelCertifications, but that didn't work. The second Where clause was still only working with the Person table. Is there a way of doing what I want? If so, how is this done?

Here's the table definitions with extraneous fields removed for brevity:

```cs
public partial class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        PersonnelCertifications = new HashSet<PersonnelCertification>();
    }

    public long ID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PersonnelCertification> PersonnelCertifications { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public partial class PersonnelCertification
{
    public long ID { get; set; }

    public long CertificationTypeID { get; set; }

    public long PersonID { get; set; }

    public virtual CertificationType CertificationType { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public partial class CertificationType
{
    public CertificationType()
    {
        PersonnelCertifications = new HashSet<PersonnelCertification>();
    }

    public long ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string CertType { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PersonnelCertification> PersonnelCertifications { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: is "write the query as SQL" an option?

Comment: I am not sure whether the provider understands `.Where(p => p.PersonnelCertifications.Any(pc => pc.CertificationType == "Operator"))`.

Comment: What did you try and what does "it didn't work" mean?

Comment: Good question, Caius. I tried adding this Where clause immediately after the second Include clause: `.Where(p => p.PersonnelCertifications.Where(pc => pc.CertificationType.CertType == "Operator"))`. However, I get error "Cannot convert lambda expression to indended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitily convertible to the delegate return type"

Comment: @mm8 your suggestion seems like it works. The provider (SQL Server) doesn't complain and at least the records I checked only included a `CertificationType.CertType == "Operator"`. Thank you!

Comment: Joining the lists may improve performance https://stackoverflow.com/a/2767742/5107490

Answer (score 0):

`.Where(p => p.PersonnelCertifications.Any(pc => pc.CertificationType == "Operator"))` should give you the people you are looking for.