# C# Grabbing subset of table based off a Hashset if Ints

Tags: c#, search, hashset

I have an `Order` and `OrderMaster` table. First I query the Master table, I then create a hashset of a column of Ints from that table. Lastly I want to get all orders that have those values.

When I do the contains, the `ToList()` fails and I get an error

> Type bool does not contain member ToList

What am I doing wrong here?

```
mappings = await _context.OrderMapping
                         .Where((OrderMapping em) => em.MOID == UID)
                         .ToListAsync();

HashSet<int> ids2 = new HashSet<int>((mappings.Select(a => a.ORDERMAPID)));

orders = await _context.Order
                       .Where(x => ids2.Contains(x.ORDERMAPID)
                       .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Why not use a `Join`? [join-where-with-linq-and-lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767709/join-where-with-linq-and-lambda)

Comment: This is what JOINs are made for. So much faster, because you do it in one trip to the db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are missing a ")" after Contains(...).
The following should work :)

```
orders = await _context.Order.Where(x => ids2.Contains(x.ORDERMAPID)).ToListAsync();
```